# What does it mean "on all shifts"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

All, Forgive me the poor English, When I was reading the document of MDS 3.0 RAI manual.I have the problem to understand this phrase "on all shifts". Please help to review it below. Thanks.

> The RAI process has multiple regulatory requirements. Federal
>   regulations at 42 CFR 483.20 (b)(1)(xviii), (g), and (h) require that
>
> (1) the assessment accurately reflects the resident’s status
>
> (2) a registered nurse conducts or coordinates each assessment with
>   the appropriate participation of health professionals
>
> (3) the assessment process includes direct observation, as well as
>   communication with the resident and direct care staff **on all shifts**.

It seems it want to tell us , The communication mentioned in the context is someone with resident or someone with direct care staff. Is it correct? Thanks.

Comment: In this case, it means "at all times." A *shift* is part of a working day. In the UK, doctors and nurses work a two-shift system -- 12 hours on-duty and 12 hours off-duty,

Comment: Thanks the nice edit. Appreciate it . next time my future questions will be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> on all shifts

A "shift" is the scheduled period of time someone works at a job, particularly at a job where there are people who work at different times and who take over for each other.  For example, nurses and police work around-the-clock, so they work in *shifts* so that no single person has to work all the time.  Shifts can be sequential (0900-1700, 1700-0100, 0100-0900) or overlapping.

> He worked the night shift for years before the factory finally moved him to days.
>
> The nurses on the morning shift at the hospital sprang into action after the accident brought in a large number of patients.

So "on all shifts" doesn't mean "at all times" but rather "on all scheduled working periods".

Comment: In this case it means "direct care staff" regardless of when they work and if they are in the building at the same time as the person doing the assessment.     Therefore the night staff need speaking to as well as the day staff, even if the person doing the assessment would rather work normal "office hours".